# React testing library element title undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I am trying to test that when I hover over an icon, a tooltip appears with certain text.

Using Jest, react testing library, and the tooltip is a MUI 4 component.

The icon and tooltip

```
<div
   data-testid="tooltip-icon"
   className={classes.infoTooltipIcon}
>
   <Tooltip
      data-testid="tooltip-text"
      title="Tooltip text"
   >
      <InfoIcon/>
   </Tooltip>
</div>
```

Slimmed down test

```
it('has a tooltip on the info icon', () => {
    render(<Component />);

    const infoIcon = screen.getByTestId('tooltip-icon');
    userEvent.hover(infoIcon); // works
    
    const infoTooltip = screen.getByTestId('tooltip-text')
    expect(infoTooltip.title).toEqual('Tooltip text);
  });
```

Currently, this results in

```
actual: undefined
expected: 'Tooltip text'
```

If I `screen.debug(infoTooltip)` the `title` is there and has the correct text, but its an `<svg/>` could this cause an issue?

Output of `screen.debug(infoTooltip)`

```
<svg
      aria-hidden="true"
      class="MuiSvgIcon-root makeStyles-center-52"
      data-testid="tooltip-text"
      focusable="false"
      title="Tooltip text"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    >
      <path
        d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm1 15h-2v-6h2v6zm0-8h-2V7h2v2z"
      />
    </svg>
```

Additionally, I have also tried `screen.getByTitle('Tooltip text')` and it does not work.

Comment: Can you try to use `queryByTestId` rather than `getByTestId`?

Comment: Same thing, `actual: undefined`, I have posted the output of `screen.debug()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like MUI applies the tooltip to whatever the child of the `<Tooltip/>` is, in my case it was the `<svg/>` generated by `<InfoIcon/>`. If you wrap the `<InfoIcon/>` in a `<span>` tag the tooltip `title` will then be applied to the `<span/>`, making it possible to explicitly look for the tooltip text.

My UI

```
<div
   data-testid="tooltip-icon"
   className={classes.infoTooltipIcon}
>
   <Tooltip
      data-testid="tooltip-text"
      title="Tooltip text"
   >
      <span>
         <InfoIcon/>
     </span>
   </Tooltip>
</div>
```

My test

```
it('has a tooltip on the info icon', () => {
    render(<Component />);

    const infoIcon = screen.getByTestId('tooltip-icon');
    userEvent.hover(infoIcon);
    
    const infoTooltip = screen.getByTestId('tooltip-text')
    expect(infoTooltip.title).toEqual('Tooltip text);
  });
```

This way if I have multiple tooltips I can ensure I'm grabbing the exact one I want via test id.

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is that you should just use the `InfoIcon` with `titleAccess` props. https://material-ui.com/api/svg-icon

```
<InfoIcon titleAccess="Tooltip Text" />
```

After that, you could test the component like this as an example.

```
expect(
      getByRole('tooltip', { hidden: true, name: 'Tooltip Text' }),
    ).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Comment: If you change the `role` from `tooltip` to `img` this works, I think MUI applies the tooltip to whatever the child element is, and in this case it was the `<svg/>` opting for a different more explicit solution because I have some components with multiple tooltips this would not work/be less clean for.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion with the span is good! If you don't want to add a span, then I think you just need to adjust the query to look for aria-hidden elements.(Since the svg has `aria-hidden=true` it gets excluded from the accessibility tree). The query would look like:
`const tooltip = screen.getByTitle("Tooltip text", { hidden: true } )`